# Return all the posts of people followed by user MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables

```
table_users: id_user | name
      table_posts: id_post | id_user | post
            table_follows: id_follow | id_follower | id_followed
```

The first table shows the users, the second one has the posts posted by them and the third one maps relationships amongst the users (follower/followed).

So for example if I have the user Mattew `id=3` and I want to retrieve the posts "posted" by all the people that he follows. In this case, Adam `id=1`, Tom `id=7` & Zoe `id=9` are followed by Mattew.

I have developed a working `php/mysql` code, but I would like to improve it using only one SQL statement.

```
//retrieve all the people followed by Mattew
$followeds=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_follows WHERE id_follower='3' /*Mattew*/");

//create an array with the ids
$array_followeds=array();

while($fwd=mysql_fetch_array($followeds)){
    $id_followed=$fwd['id_followed'];
    $array_followeds[]="id_user='".$id_followed."'";
}

//if exists people followed by Mattew
if(count($array_followeds)>0){
    $array_followeds=implode(' OR ', $array_followeds);
}else{/*$array_followeds="id_user=0";*/}

//main query: shows all the posts of the people Mattew follows
$main_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_posts WHERE ($array_followeds) AND id_user!='3'/*Mattew*/");

while($posts=mysql_fetch_array($main_query)){
      /*results */
}
```

I would like suggestions of how to improve the SQL query using a single statement and avoiding use of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose what fields you need

```
SELECT f.*, p.*
FROM table_follows f
JOIN table_posts p
  ON f.id_followed = p.id_user 
WHERE f.id_follower = '3'
```

Comment: `ON f.id_follow(er) = p.id_user` ?